# Flash Player in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

I need to create a E-learning site in SharePoint 2016. It will contain a flash player which will play all flash files (from a library) in single player one by one (same as video gallery web parts).

I have seen the solutions which play only single flash file in a Content Editor web part but this will not suffice my requirement as I cannot add content editor for every flash file in the library.

Comment: Flash is dead. It's also a massive security risk. It's time to move on. 
If you MUST use flash, I think you're going to be limited to multiple IFRAMEs in a Content Editor Webpart. 
Assuming the flash files are not interactive, have you thought about converting the flash files to video files instead?

Comment: Easier said than done @nulldata. If the OP has a bunch of flash files and instructions from higher ups to build a solution around them, telling him "flash is dead" isn't going to do him any good.